# VBA DOM SelectSingleNode with xpath in SOAP

Tags: xml, vba, dom, xpath

Here's my XML file:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/10.5">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:listTransPattern>
         <searchCriteria>
            <pattern>%</pattern>
            <routePartitionName>%</routePartitionName>
            <description>%</description>
         </searchCriteria>
         <returnedTags>
            <pattern>?</pattern>
            <routePartitionName>?</routePartitionName>
            <description>?</description>
         </returnedTags>
      </ns:listTransPattern>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried to add an element **in parallel with** `<returnedTags>`.  How shall I implement it in VBA?  Thank you very much!

Comment: It's a typo.  I fixed it. Still need help on how to add an element in parallel with <returnedTags>.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I posted an answer for that. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That's what I was looking for - reference namespace in XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like as follows.

If you want to select that element with an XPath expression, you must first set the appropriate selection namespace using  `.setProperty "SelectionLanguage"`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim xTEST As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    With xTEST
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .async = False
        .setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns=""http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/10.5"""
        If Not .Load("C:\Test.xml") Then
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
        End If

        Dim a As IXMLDOMElement
        Set a = .SelectSingleNode("//ns:listTransPattern").appendChild(.createElement("Status"))

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand that XML file can have one root only.  But if you looked at the XML file in my original post, the node I tried to add was not really at the root.  It's just the VBA thought it's the root in the 'ns' namespace.  So my question is - how do I change the namespace to workaround it?

Comment: For my education purpose, what is the syntax to reference a namespace in SelectSingleNode(XPath) without defining the namespace first?  Thank you!

Comment: To use xpath for that element you must specify a namespace. Alternatives may include removing the name space from the document and traversing the structure without xpath.